# Laravel Eloquent and MySQL SOUNDS LIKE and different in Laravel request input() and get()

Tags: php, mysql, search, laravel-5

I'm trying to implement some flexibility in my Laravel search query using MySQL SOUNDS LIKE function. My query with MySQL 'LIKE' function works fine and look like this.

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {

        $search = $this->posts->where(function($query) use($request) {

                $keywords = $request->keywords;

                $keywords = explode(' ', $keywords);

                for($x = 0; $x < count($keywords); $x++)
                {
                    $query->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$keywords[$x].'%');
                    }
        })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(12);
.....
}
```

Than I try to add `'SOUNDS LIKE'` in my query:

```
$query->orWhere('title', 'SOUNDS LIKE', '%'.$keywords[$x].'%');
```

But this doesn't work. Deosn't return any results. What I'm making wrong?

Also, in my function I'm using `$request->keywords` without `input()` or `get()`.

```
$request->keywords;
$request->input('keywords');
$request->get('keywords');
```

Is my method insecure? What of this method is most secure?
I was wondering what is different in this few request method ant what is best solution?

Answer (score 1):

you can try remove '%' character, like:

```
$query->orWhere('title', 'SOUNDS LIKE', $keywords[$x].'%');
```

Comment: tried the SOUNDS LIKE only and worked perfectly for me, thank you